# validating 10 digit phone number

Tags: regex

I am  new to  RegEx I am trying to validate a phone number with 10 digit and `+` and 2 digit country code as optional. Tried with few regex but  I'm not able to make `+` and the country code as optional `^[+]*\d[0-9]{10,12}$`.  Can anyone tell me  where I'm wrong.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enclose the first two digits with an optional non-capturing group:

```
^[+]?(?:[0-9]{2})?[0-9]{10}$
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uWedjw/1).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[+]?` - an optional `+`
- `(?:[0-9]{2})?` - an optional *sequence* of 2 digits
- `[0-9]{10}` - 10 digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: @OP So I was incorrect in assuming the plus and country code was "a package", since this can have the plus with 10 digits? Then it's not really, as the title says, a 10 digit phone number - it's 8-10 digits with optional country code.

Comment: @ClasG: The total digit amount validated with this regex is 10 or 12, not 8-10. I understand the `+` is optional because OP has `*` quantifier beside it. The question lacks the details,  so I tried to use OP regex and only introduce the change to make the country code digits optional.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly (it's a bit fuzzy with the optional part), none of the given answers will do what you want. So here's my go at it ;)

```
^(?:\+\d\d)?\d{10}$
```

This starts with an **optional** non capturing group with the `+` **and** the country code. Then followed by the 10 digits.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wyvQsp/2).

Comment: Still, this might be useful if someone needs a `+` to be "bound" to the country code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
^([0|\+[0-9]{1,5})?([7-9][0-9]{9})$
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you using Html5 pattern? if yes, below could be your answer,

```
<input type="text" pattern="[\+][\(]\d{2}[\)]\d{10}" required/>
```

e.g. format: +(91)1234567890

Comment: Sorry, but that's a badly written regex, and it doesn't fulfill the one criteria given.

Comment: @ClasG, ok, thanks for correcting, i tried with both criteria one is with and without + and brackted 2 digit number i.e. (91), for updated pattern

Comment: `^(?:[\+][\(]\d{2}[\)])?\d{10}$` i have tested this one for below example, 1234567890, +(91)1234567890

Comment: There are no parentheses in the criteria. (Could be that this regex isn't checking number to input/display, but communicating with a PBX or something...)